# How to put an object within a canvas using onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

This website's purpose is to display maps using buttons, and then have the user click on a country to visit a website via invisible `<a>` tags. This is achieved by creating a canvas that becomes unhidden onclick and changing the canvas background according to the button. The end goal is to have the `<a>` tags appear when its corresponding button is clicked and then disappear when another button is pressed. However, when the button is pressed, the `<a>` tags spawn above the canvas and not in it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta  name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="map.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Where do you wanna go?</h1>
    <table>
<!--North America-->
        <tr><td><button id="nA" onclick="northAmerica()">North America</button></tr></td>

            <td><button id="nA2" onclick="nNorthAmerica()">Northern North America</button></td>             

            <td><button id="nA4" onclick="cenAmerica()">Central America</button></td>
                <a href="https://www.google.com/" id="x">HELLO</a>
                <a href="https://www.google.com/" id="y">hello</a>
                <td><canvas class="map" id="c"></canvas></td>   
    </table>
```

map.js

```
//NORTH AMERICA
function northAmerica(){

    let nA2 = document.getElementById("nA2");
    let nA3 = document.getElementById("nA3");
    let nA4 = document.getElementById("nA4");

    let x = document.getElementById("x");
    let y = document.getElementById("y");

    nA2.style.display = "block";
    nA3.style.display = "block";
    nA4.style.display = "block";

    var c = document.getElementById("c");

    c.style.display="block";
}

function nNorthAmerica(){
    c.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/ipPrjz1.jpg')";
    c.style.backgroundSize = "65em 45em";
    c.style.display="block";
    x.style.display = "block";
}

function cenAmerica(){
    c.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/84LVJaY.gif')";
    c.style.backgroundSize = "65em 45em";
    y.style.display = "block";

}
```

```css
/*The purpose of this block is to hide the elements until they are called upon*/
#nA2, #nA3, #nA4, #c, #x, #y{
    display:none;
}
button{
    width:10em;
    height:5em;
    font:sans-serif;
}
.map{
    width:65em;
    height:35em;
}
```

I expect that function `nNorthAmerica` spawns the element `x` onto the page since by default it is hidden, and same for `cenAmerica` and `y`. However, I do not know how to have the `<a>` tags appear within the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to overlay the links - HELLO & hello - on top of the canvas?

This can be done by wrapping the **canvas** and the **a** elements in a **div**. If you then set the position attribute af the canvas to **relative** and the a elements **absolute** it's origin will be the top-left corner of the canvas.

Here's an example:

```js
function northAmerica() {

  let nA2 = document.getElementById("nA2");
  let nA3 = document.getElementById("nA3");
  let nA4 = document.getElementById("nA4");

  let x = document.getElementById("x");
  let y = document.getElementById("y");

  nA2.style.display = "block";
  nA3.style.display = "block";
  nA4.style.display = "block";

  var c = document.getElementById("c");

  c.style.display = "block";
}

function nNorthAmerica() {
  c.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/ipPrjz1.jpg')";
  c.style.backgroundSize = "65em 45em";
  c.style.display = "block";
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function cenAmerica() {
  c.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/84LVJaY.gif')";
  c.style.backgroundSize = "65em 45em";
  y.style.display = "block";

}
```

```css
#nA2,
#nA3,
#nA4,
#c,
#x,
#y {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

button {
  width: 10em;
  height: 5em;
  font: sans-serif;
}

.map {
  width: 65em;
  height: 35em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="nA" onclick="northAmerica()">North America</button></tr>
  </td>

  <td><button id="nA2" onclick="nNorthAmerica()">Northern North America</button></td>

  <td><button id="nA4" onclick="cenAmerica()">Central America</button></td>

</table>
<div><canvas class="map" id="c"></canvas>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/" id="x">HELLO</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/" id="y">hello</a></div>
```